# how to end an ongoing function

Tags: jquery, html, menu, tabs, fadein

I have made this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#tabs a").hover(function(){
        rod = this.id
        $('div.tabber').hide();
        $('#tabber_' + rod).fadeIn();
        $("div#tabs a").removeClass("tab_active");
        $(this).addClass("tab_active");
    });
});
```

and the html:

```
<div id="tabs"> <!-- begin #tabs -->
        <!-- begin #tab1 --><a id="tab1" class="tab_active">What are you?</a> <!-- end #tab2 -->
        <!-- begin #tab2 --><a id="tab2">Products</a> <!-- end #tab2 -->
        <!-- begin #tab3 --><a id="tab3">Services</a> <!-- end #tab3 -->
        <!-- begin #tab4 --><a id="tab4">Contact Us</a> <!-- end #tab4 -->
      </div> <!-- end #tabs -->

<div id="tabs_tabber"> <!-- begin #tabs_tabber -->
            <div class="tabber" id="tabber_tab1"> <!-- begin #tabber_tab1 -->
                <a id="m_btn1" href="#">business</a><br />
                <a id="m_btn" href="#">private</a><br />
            </div><!-- end #tabber_tab1 -->
            <div class="tabber" id="tabber_tab2" style="display:none;"> <!-- begin #tabber_tab2 -->
                <a id="m_btn1" href="#">Apple</a><br />
                <a id="m_btn" href="#">Microsoft</a><br />

            </div> <!-- end #tabber_tab2 -->
            <div class="tabber" id="tabber_tab3" style="display:none;"> <!-- begin #tabber_tab3 -->
                <a id="m_btn1" href="#">Education</a><br />
                <a id="m_btn" href="#">Installation</a><br />
            </div> <!-- end #tabber_tab3 -->
            <div class="tabber" id="tabber_tab4" style="display:none;"> <!-- begin #tabber_tab4 -->
                <a id="m_btn1" href="#">Menu Btn</a><br />
                <a id="m_btn" href="#">Menu Btn</a><br />
                <a id="m_btn" href="#">Menu Btn</a><br />
            </div> <!-- end #tabber_tab4 -->
        </div> <!-- end #tabs_tabber -->
```

I have noticed, that if I do the .fadeIn effect there will be a problem. If the client is 'hover' a tab and then directly hover another tab, the function will not work because it is not done before the other tab requires the same function again, which will result in totally "not-good-looking" fading menu.

It is difficult to explain because of my bad english, but if someone please could try just look at it and perhaps telling me if there is some way to end the function before it will be requested again.

I also know that I can do the .click function instead of .hover function, but I rather want the .hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `$('#tabber_' + rod).fadeIn();` to:

```
$('#tabber_' + rod).stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
```

The `.stop()` will stop any current animations on the element(s) which is useful if you want to queue-up another animation. Also I changed `.fadeOut()` to `.fadeTo()` because when you use `.stop()`, if you stop the animation half of the way though it will get stuck half-transparent.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4vLty/

Comment: You solved the case..! ^_^You don't know how many hours I've been spending on trying to stop the function and making delays... Can you explain me why the script is doing what it does?

Comment: When you say it like that it's fairly logical

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop --> This documentation will explain what `.stop()` does. Short-answer, it stops previous animations on the element(s) from completing so the new animation can start immediately.

Comment: I am sorry. Just one more thing. Do you know why it is flashing on the selections when you 'mouseout' on the tabs? (looked at the link you sent me)

Comment: You know... Never mind... I figured out, that if I use the event .mouseover instead of .hover, the flashing won't appear.. Thank you again for your help!